# Should rep and badges carry over from programmers to meta.programmers?

Tags: support, reputation

I just flipped over to meta for the first time and started browsing & voting, and my rep (but not my badges) carried over from programmers. Is this the way it's supposed to work? I would expect that my "score" would either carry over in entirety or not at all, and I'd start on meta with 0 rep and 0 badges...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reputation does, badges don't: it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). However, there's a lag time between the time you gain rep on the main site and when it reflects as your rep total on meta.

Answer (score 4):

It's a trade-off between starting with nothing and having nothing to gain by participating.

The reason repuation **does transfer** is so that you have the same privileges here, as well as others being able to see your main-site participation.  By consequence you gain no reputation from Meta.

Badges **don't transfer** so that you can still earn something here.

Comment: But the "Quorum" badge on programmers can only be earned via actions on meta. So does this badge transfer the other way from meta to programmers?

Comment: You can see in http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/badges that there is no `Quorum` badge on Meta.

Comment: Yes, I get that there is no quorum badge on Meta. What I don't get is that on Programmers, I earned a quorum badge for THIS post here on Meta. Why am I earning badges in Programmer for an action taken solely on Meta? It seems more intuitive to me that the quorum badge should exist ONLY on meta...

Comment: @Greg the point is to provide some insight from main into a user's participation in meta.  You shouldn't think of them as two separate and equal sites.  Your member record as a whole involves both together.

Comment: I buy it. Thanks for the explanation.